# Is there a way to capture screen when menu bars are opened?

Tags: gnome, screenshot

On GNOME, I would like to capture a screen to show a special situation where I am on *IDEA IntelliJ*, when two menus are opened.

Main Window → Menu Bar 1 → Menu Bar 2

But as soon as I open one of these menu bars, nor the Windows key to call the Capture tool, nor the Print Screen Key will work (there's no image captured in the `images` folder).

As if the opening of one menu made GNOME coming entirely modal.
Provided I close the menus, I can use capture and print screen again. But it's not what I want...

Does a way exist to do a print screen in any situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many screenshot utils, among them `xfce4-screenshooter` and `mate-screenshot`, allow for setting a delay time. That way you have enough time to open said menus.

One of the most basic ones would be:

`scrot -d 5`

See [man scrot](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/scrot/scrot.1.en.html)

Answer (score 1):

```bash
sleep 5; any_console_utility_which_makes_screenshots
```